# Rails Checkout SSL heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku

I have my app deployed with heroku and have a SSL configured to one of my subdomain(secure.mydomain.com). I  would like only order part of my app to use this ssl so in my orders controller I have a before filter to redirect the request to my secure subdomain. However all the session information is lost when it is redirected. I think because of the subdomain. How do I redirect this so that session information (cart info which is stored in db and some id information) can be retrieved. Can some one help please.

THanks
KIran

Comment: Ideally, the entire site should be available via SSL and should redirect users to the SSL version automatically.

Comment: looks like my boss is having an issue setting up the entire site available via SSL. So I was trying this approach.

Comment: also just wanted to ask if there is a preferred way to handle secure transactions in rails other than using redirecting.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your config/intializers/session_store.rb change it to

```
Yourapp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => '_yourapp_session', :domain=>:all
```

The secret-sauce is the domain... When set to all, cookies will be stored across all subdomains and the main domain.

Comment: also just wanted to ask if there is a preferred way to handle secure transactions in rails other than using redirecting.