# Subdomain Session Not Working in Rails 2.3 and Rails 3 on Heroku with/without a Custom Domain?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, heroku, subdomain

So I have two heroku apps:

- http://production-app.com (mapped from http://production-app.heroku.com)
- http://development-app.heroku.com

On `production-app.com`, I have several subdomains using the Heroku custom domains addon with Zerigo (not the wildcard domain addon):

- http://blog.production-app.com
- http://api.production-app.com

On `development-app.heroku.com`, I also have those custom subdomains, but since I don't have a custom domain, I just use the [wildcard addon](http://addons.heroku.com/custom_domains).

In my `routes.rb`, using [Subdomain-Fu](https://github.com/mbleigh/subdomain-fu), I have the subdomains working locally and on both Heroku apps.

The issue I'm facing now is, *how do I keep the session in sync between all the subdomains*?

I have tried adding this to `production.rb`:

```
ActionController::CgiRequest::DEFAULT_SESSION_OPTIONS.update(:session_domain => '.production-app.com')
```

And even combinations of this:

```
begin
  config.action_controller.session[:domain] = '.production-app.com'
  config.action_controller.session[:session_domain] = '.production-app.com'
rescue
  config.action_controller.session = {:domain => '.production-app.com', :session_domain => ".production-app.com"}
end
```

...and for the dev site, both of these:

```
ActionController::CgiRequest::DEFAULT_SESSION_OPTIONS.update(:session_domain => '.heroku.com')
# or
ActionController::CgiRequest::DEFAULT_SESSION_OPTIONS.update(:session_domain => '.development-app.heroku.com')
```

None of those keep the session between subdomains.  How do I get this working when I have a custom domain and when I'm just running off a Heroku subdomain?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your config/initializers/session_store.rb, tell rails to set the cookie across all domains:

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => '_yourapp_session', :domain=>:all
```

Same as this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606041/rails-checkout-ssl-heroku)

If you are wanting to persist your session between "development-app.heroku.com" and "production-app.com" that cannot be done unless those are the same codebase. If they are the same codebase, then use a before_filter on your application controller to redirect to production-app.com

Answer (score 0):

> On development-app.heroku.com, I also have those custom subdomains,
>   but since I don't have a custom domain, I just use the [wildcard addon](http://addons.heroku.com/custom_domains).

Is this addon still available for using custom subdomains like `api.mydevdomain.herokuapp.com` ?