# How do I share sessions between 2 Heroku apps?

Tags: session, heroku, rack

In the context of [What is the difference between a Cookie and Redis Session store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14347540/what-is-the-difference-between-a-cookie-and-redis-session-store) , how can I share session data among Heroku apps (Sinatra frontend with Rack API backend)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two questions have suggestions on how to accomplish this:

- [Subdomain Session Not Working in Rails 2.3 and Rails 3 on Heroku with/without a Custom Domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5340989/subdomain-session-not-working-in-rails-2-3-and-rails-3-on-heroku-with-without-a)
- [Rails Checkout SSL heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606041/rails-checkout-ssl-heroku)

Comment: Hmmm, both of those answers are Rails specific (and the question is not). Anybody have solutions without a Rails dependency?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you would want to do is use an external session store (such as Redis), and simply copy the Redis environment values from the first app into the second. You should then be able to access the same session data from both Heroku apps.

EDIT 1:

It also occurs to me that as it is two seperate Heroku apps, you will (probably) have two seperate domains/subdomains. You will need to ensure that your session cookie allows access from both the domains.